# Find and replace string in folder name using command line

Tags: shell, findandmodify

How can I replace a string in all my folder names in one directory. For example if I have these folders

hellojoe
hellomary
hellosusan

I want to change these to

worldjoe
worldmary
worldsusan

Comment: Are you trying to avoid changing the names of regular files?

Comment: Yes I would like to change the folder names only, without touching the files. In my case, that's not a concern, since there are no files in that folder, so my provided answer works. But being more explicit would make a better answer of course.

Comment: In the answer you've given, just add `-type d` to restrict to directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this command works

```
find . -name 'hello*' -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/hello/world}"' -- {} \;
```